# Allowing multiple users to deploy over ssh and git

Tags: git, github, ssh

We've got a website up and running, called `sasse`. We use a simple SSH and Git (Github) deployment strategy, where code is simply `pull`:ed from the Github account to the deployment server (and refreshed).

Currently, the website's files are owned by a `sasse` user on the server, but with group write permissions. The files are located in `/home/sasse/sasse`.

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 sasse sasse  4096 Nov 16 07:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 sasse sasse  4096 Nov 19 15:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 sasse sasse 45948 Nov 10 05:42 CHANGELOG.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 sasse sasse   925 Nov 10 05:42 COPYRIGHT.txt
...
```

This means that it works fine to do `git pull` when you're logged in as `sasse` on the server, but if I do it as my personal account (sudo account which has been added to the `sasse` group), any changed files will belong to me; my primary group is not `sasse`. I.e. after pulling a change which affected COPYRIGHT.txt:

```
drwxrwxr-x 10 sasse sasse    4096 Nov 16 07:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 sasse sasse    4096 Nov 19 15:13 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 sasse sasse   45948 Nov 10 05:42 CHANGELOG.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 victor victor   925 Nov 10 05:42 COPYRIGHT.txt
```

This means that I have to remember to do `chown -R sasse:sasse .` if I want to keep the original ownership status -- which is necessary if someone else is going to be able to pull next time. And they quite possibly are!

It is necessary that more than one person can deploy code to our server, so the `sasse` account is impersonal. I didn't want people to log into it, but to use a personal account with the relevant group memberships/permissions.

Questions:

- What is the best way to handle a situation where multiple people need access to deploy code on the same server?

  - Should we simply allow everyone to use the `sasse` account for deployment instead?*
  - Should we maintain a strategy where users have group access (or sudo access) to the repository but somehow work around the problem of permissions getting messed up? If so, how? Can I make git pull "as a specific user"?

<sup>* Possibly by adding public keys to `authorized_keys` and not letting `sasse` edit that file itself</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Go with [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) and appropriate after-receive (or similar) hooks. One of them should be a checkout to the ref just pushed.